# Python GUI not capturing zeromq message

Tags: python, user-interface, zeromq, pyqt5

I have a small program where I am not receiving a response from the server.
This is using python 3.4 and latest zeromq and pyqt5 on Ubuntu 14.04.
The client GUI sends a message to the server which gets it and responds but the client does not see the response.

Here is the code:
miniServer.py:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream

# Prepare for client socket
ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
sIn = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
urlIn = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:1234'
sIn.bind(urlIn)
# Prepare for sockets to GUI and Web
guiCalled = False
webCalled = False
urlGui = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:2345'
urlWeb = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:3456'
sGUI = None
sWeb = None

def __GetConfig__(sender, data):
    if "GUI" == sender:
        print("Sending back config list to GUI")
        sGUI.send_string("From Server to GUI")
    elif "WEB" == sender:
        sWeb.send_string("From Server to Web")
def __CheckGUICalled__():
    # Used to only connnect once
    global guiCalled
    global sGUI
    if not guiCalled:
        print("Connected to client GUI at port 2345")
        guiCalled = True
        sGUI = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        sGUI.connect(urlGui)
def __CheckWebCalled__():
    # Used to only connnect once
    global webCalled
    global sWeb
    if not webCalled:
        webCalled = True
        sWeb = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        sWeb.connect(urlWeb)

actions = {
    "GET_CONFIG": __GetConfig__}
clients = {
    "GUI": __CheckGUICalled__,
    "WEB": __CheckWebCalled__}

def check_msg(msg):
    newStr = msg[0].decode("utf-8", "strict")
    if newStr.count(":") == 2:
        [sender, command, data] = newStr.split(":")
        print("Sender: " + sender + ", Command: " + command + ", Data: " + data)
        # connect if not already done
        clients.get(sender, lambda: None)()
        # execute the command sent from client
        actions.get(command, lambda: None)(sender, data)

# register the check_msg callback to be fired
# whenever there is a message on our socket
stream = ZMQStream(sIn)
stream.on_recv(check_msg)

# Setup callback handling the XMOS
tic = time.time()
def xmos_handler():
    # just testing
    print("Loop time: %.3f" % (time.time() - tic))

pc = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(xmos_handler, 200)
pc.start()

# start the eventloop
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

miniGUI.py:

```
import os
import sys
import zmq
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from zmq.eventloop.zmqstream import ZMQStream

# prepare out socket to server
ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
sOut = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
sOut.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:1234')

# handle inputs from server
def check_msg(msg):
    newStr = msg[0].decode("utf-8", "strict")
    print("Message: " + newStr + " received")
sIn = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
sIn.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:2345')
stream = ZMQStream(sIn)
stream.on_recv(check_msg)

# setup window
class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        nameLabel = QLabel("Name:")
        self.nameLine = QLineEdit()
        self.submitButton = QPushButton("Submit")
        buttonLayout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(nameLabel)
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(self.nameLine)
        buttonLayout1.addWidget(self.submitButton)
        self.submitButton.clicked.connect(self.submitContact)
        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(buttonLayout1, 0, 1)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.setWindowTitle("For Test: GUI:GET_CONFIG:0")

    def submitContact(self):
        name = self.nameLine.text()
        sOut.send_string(name)
        print("Message " + name + " sent")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Form()
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Start the server first in one treminal:

> python3.4 miniServer.py

and then the GUI:

> python3.4 miniGUI.py

Writing the string in the edit widget:

> GUI:GET_CONFIG:0

and pressing the submit button will print on the server console:

> Sender: GUI, Command: GET_CONFIG, Data: 0
>
> Connected to client GUI at port 2345
>
> Sending back config list to GUI

and on the GUI console will only

> Message GUI:GET_CONFIG:0 sent

be written whereas the expected result should have been:

> Message GUI:GET_CONFIG:0 sent
>
> Message: From Server to GUI received

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use socket type REQ/REP instead of PUSH/PULL which makes the code also much cleaner.